# Figure with caption inside a TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

After searching for hours, I hope someone could help me with my issue!

I have a command with tikzpicture to draw a box with a title to highlight some text in my document:

```
\newcommand*{\magicbox}[2]{
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% the box
\node[rectangle,draw=fondtitre!100,fill=fonddeboite!100,inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt] (mybox)
{
\begin{minipage}{12cm}
#2
\end{minipage}
};
% title of the box
\node[fill=fondtitre!100, text=white, rectangle] at (mybox.north) {\sffamily\textbf{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}
```

Now, I would like to add a figure inside the box, and that's where I struggle to find a solution.
I tried to do the following:

```
\newcommand*{\magicbox}[2]{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            % the box
                \node[rectangle,draw=fondtitre!100,fill=fonddeboite!100,inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt] (mybox)
            {
                \begin{minipage}{12cm}
                    #2
                \end{minipage}
             };
            \node[inner sep=0pt] at (1,-1) (image) {\includegraphics[scale=0.20]{myfigure} \label{fig:myfigurelabel} \caption{the caption of my figure}};
            % title of the box
            \node[fill=fondtitre!100, text=white, rectangle] at (mybox.north) {\sffamily\textbf{#1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}
```

However, I get my figure in the middle of the box, with no caption.

I didn't find any example of a picture with a caption inside a tikzpicture on the internet.

Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. We're going to need a MWE including your used packages. The `\caption` macro can get changed very much depending on the packages and settings you use. Usually, you should get an error message that you've used it outside a float.

Comment: If by "figure" ou mean `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`, you can't put those inside anything.  If you mean a tikzpicture, put can't (or shouldn't) put those inside another tikzpicture.  You can howver use a savebox.

Comment: You can use `\captionof{figure}{<your caption>}` inside your `minipage`/inside a `node`. You'll need to load a package that provides `\captionof` if it isn't defined for you (in that case, I'd use the `capt-of` package).

Comment: It seems that you want to use Ti*k*Z to draw some kind of box. Did you have a look at the `tcolorbox` package?